# PostgreSQL user access

Tags: postgresql, database-administration

Can a read-only user create the temp tables in PostgreSQL.

If not, is there any way to give access only to create temp tables.

please advice, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give him the "TEMPORARY" privilege:

```
GRANT TEMPORARY ON DATABASE {dbname} TO {role}
```

For a full explanation of permissions you can check the docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-grant.html

Comment: thank you, if it is on a specific schema?

Comment: @Raju temporary tables exist in their own schema, that's why you give permissions on database.